# How to use the property of object inside the object in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to use the property of object inside the object, like this:

```
var obj = {
  a: 1
  b: this.obj + this.obj.a

}
```

Comment: Before the object has been initialized, you can't reference its other properties like that. Either assign on a subsequent line after the object has been initialized or use the same strategy in an IIFE.

Comment: `this.obj` would be `undefined` unless `this` is the global object and `obj` is a global variable. Are you wanting to compute `b` again every time it's accessed, or just when you're building the object?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have `computed` property with your object, think about it similar to a `getter` in object-oriented class.

You can do something like:

```
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2, 
  c: () => this.a + this.b
}
```

Later, you can access `obj.c()` to get the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question got me thinking about "Why not creating an object out of values and getters" - it is probably an overkill for your requirements, but i had to think this out :)

```js
/*
** This function creates an object by rewriting the values of the first 
** object as "value properties" (meaning the values stay as they are but 
** can be accessed and modified like properties), while the second object 
** expects functions that act as getters, which can access the values 
** defined in the first object as well the getters from itself.
*/
const LetsBeLazy = function(values, lazy) {
  for(let key in values) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
      value: values[key],
      configurable: true,
      writable: true
    });
  }
  for(key in lazy) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
      get: lazy[key]
    });
  }
  return this;
}

// Pointless example to get the point through :)
var obj = LetsBeLazy({
  // These values stay as they are and can be 
  // accessed and changed from outside with the property notation
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  salutation: 'Mr.',
  buildFullName: (random) => `${salutation} ${firstName} ${lastName} (${random})`
}, {
  // These functions are lazily evaluated and can access other getters
  // as well the values from the previous object - notice that since
  // they are properties, they can't be called like functions.
  sayHello: () => `Hello ${buildFullName(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10))}`,
  sayHelloWithABang: () => `${sayHello}!`
});

document.write(obj.sayHello + "<br>");

obj.firstName = 'Jane';
obj.salutation = 'Mrs.';
document.write(obj.sayHelloWithABang + "<br>");

document.write(obj.buildFullName('X') + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference an object that hasn't been created yet.

Would something like this help?

```
var obj = {
  a: 1
}
obj.b = obj + obj.a
```

This will give the same result as you seem to expect from the code above.